# Replace text in div and not in other elements with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have an issue, here is my html

```
<div id="slider" class="hidden">
 <input type="button">X</input>
</div>
```

and here is my Jquery:

```
var el = $('#slider').clone();
el.removeClass("hidden");
el.text("My humble text");
$("#otherdiv").append(el);
```

So the issue is that when i execut this jquery, everything is replaced also the button with X .. because it seemed to be as text.

My question is how to i add text only to the div, but i let the other elements with the texts be as they are ...?

Comment: You are looking for the `.append()` method.

Comment: Side note, typo in your line `var el = $('#slider).clone();` missing `'`.

Comment: An input is a self closing element, is the X supposed to come after the button, or should you really set it as the value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use .append() instead of .html()

```
var el = $('#slider').clone();
el.removeClass("hidden");
el.append("My humble text");
$("#otherdiv").append(el);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mJbct/)

Also

- The resulting html will contain multiple elements with the id `slider`, you will have to change the id of the cloned element
- `<input type="button">X</input>` should be `<input type="button" value="X">`

Comment: oh it works thanks, and thanks for the pointing me to this ID issue ... maybe i should change it :)